# Not able to Set RecordId for Record in Apex Class

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, wrapper-class

I am trying to create Account, Contact and User from Custom Aura Lightning Component but iam `not able to set RecordId` for the Record.
Below is the Method that iam using for Record Creation. In the parameters iam getting values from Aura Component JS Controller but when iam updating recordId it is showing null don't know why.
I've tried with providing hard Code Id for `rTypeId` but still getting null
can you guide me what wrong iam doing here.

`LApplicant` and `SAuthority` are the Picklist Values passed in `registeringAs` Parameter of Apex Method

FYI - The same code iam running in Anonymous block is working and iam getting RecordTypeId there

```
    public static Final String L_APPLICANT = 'LApplicant';
    public static Final String S_AUTHORITY = 'SAuthority';
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String submitForm(Account act, Contact con, String registeringAs, User usr){
        
        String result = '';
        try{
            resultWrapper uWrap;
            List<AccountContactRelation> acrList = new List<AccountContactRelation>();
            String rTypeId;
            rTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get(registeringAs.equalsIgnoreCase(S_AUTHORITY) ? 'AUTHORITY' : (registeringAs.equalsIgnoreCase(L_APPLICANT) ? 'L_APPLICANT' : 'APPLICANT')).getRecordTypeId();
            
            
            if(con != null && String.isNotBlank(con.Id)){
                acrList = [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM AccountContactRelation WHERE 
                                                                   Account.FirstTime__c = true AND 
                                                                   Account.RecordTypeId = :rTypeId AND 
                                                                   ContactId = :con.Id LIMIT 1];
                                                        
                act.RecordTypeId = rTypeId;
                //There already exists an account so update the same
                if(acrList != null && !acrList.isEmpty()){
                    update con;
                    
                    act.Id = String.isNotBlank(act.Id) ? act.Id : acrList[0].AccountId;
                    update act;
                }
                //Create new Account
                else{
                    act.FirstTime__c = true;
                    insert act;
                    
                    con.AccountId = act.Id;
                    update con;
                    
                    result =  con.Id;
                }
            }
            
            //insert both account and contact
            else{
                system.debug(act.Name);
                if(act.id == null){
                    act.Name = String.isNotBlank(act.Name) ? act.Name : (String.isNotBlank(act.First_Name__c)? act.First_Name__c+' ' : '') +(String.isNotBlank(act.Middle_Name__c)? act.Middle_Name__c+' ' : '')+ (String.isNotBlank(act.Last_Name__c)? act.Last_Name__c : '');
                    act.ownerId = userInfo.getUserId();
                }
                
                
                act.RecordTypeId = rTypeId;
                
                if(string.isBlank(act.MA_Permit_Number__c)){
                    act.MA_Permit_Status__c ='Prospective';
                }
                if( string.isBlank(act.NA_Certification_Number__c) ){
                    act.NA_Certification_Status__c ='Prospective';
                }
                if( string.isBlank(act.NFA_License_Number__c)){
                    act.NFA_License_Status__c ='Prospective';
                }
                system.debug(act);
                act.FirstTime__c = true;
                upsert act;
                
                if(con != null){
                    con.AccountId = act.Id;
                    insert con;
                    //AccountContactRelation acr = new AccountContactRelation();
                    //acr.ContactId = con.Id;
                    //acr.AccountId = act.Id;    
                    //acr.IsDirect = true;
                    //insert acr;
                }
            }
            uWrap = new resultWrapper();
            uWrap.firstName = registeringAs.equalsIgnoreCase(L_APPLICANT) ?   act.First_Name__c : con.FirstName ;
            uWrap.lastName = registeringAs.equalsIgnoreCase(L_APPLICANT) ? act.Last_Name__c  : con.LastName;
            uWrap.email = registeringAs.equalsIgnoreCase(L_APPLICANT) ?  act.primary_email__c : con.Email;
            uWrap.contactId = (con != null && String.isNotBlank(con.Id)) ? con.Id : null ;
            uWrap.registeringAs = registeringAs;
            uWrap.priorEmail = usr != null ? usr.Email : null;
            uWrap.userId = usr != null ? usr.Id : null;
            uWrap.accountId = registeringAs.equalsIgnoreCase(L_APPLICANT) ?  act.Id : null ;
            uWrap.RecordTypeId = rTypeId;
            result += ' ## '+uWrap;
             result += ' @@ ' + createUpdateUser(uWrap);
            
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            result +=  act +' '+ con+ '##' + ex.getMessage()+' '+ex.getStackTraceString();
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    public class resultWrapper{
        public String firstName;
        public String lastName;
        public String email;
        public String contactId;
        public String registeringAs;
        public String priorEmail;
        public String userId;
        public String accountId;
        public String RecordTypeId;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the code below, do you have AUTHORITY, L_APPLICANT, and APPLICANT three record types in your org, I think `L_APPLICANT` may a wrong record type API name.

```java
rTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get(registeringAs.equalsIgnoreCase(S_AUTHORITY) ? 'AUTHORITY' : (registeringAs.equalsIgnoreCase(L_APPLICANT) ? 'L_APPLICANT' : 'APPLICANT')).getRecordTypeId();
```

Or change your code to

```java
rTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get(registeringAs.equalsIgnoreCase(S_AUTHORITY) ? 'AUTHORITY' : (registeringAs.equalsIgnoreCase(L_APPLICANT) ? 'APPLICANT' : 'L_APPLICANT')).getRecordTypeId();
```

Debug this statement in the Anonymous Window first.

Comment: Wrapper is just for information but in DML it still showing null and that was my question

Comment: Sorry about the answer.

Comment: Regarding the new Answer - I've tried the statement that iam using in Anonymous block and `it is working fine and showing recordTypeId.`
There is nothing wrong in that code.
Whereas if i try to give hardCode Id for this variable(rTypeId ) iam still getting null result.